# How to create memo in magento?

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I have an order with paid invoice and a want to refund it.
Using PayPal express checkout(Sale) account.
How i change the invoice status and cancel order in Magento.

When i click on Refund button it respond me "Cannot create memo"

Comment: look in var/log for any logged errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant create a credit memo, may it be because of the following reasons:

The invoice for that particular order has not been created.

The grand total of that order is zero (may be after applying discount).

Have you ticked the check-box that appears just above the refund amount ??(i.e whether to mail the customer the credit memo.) If Yes, then the email sending is failing and memo is not getting created.